# SQL injection into IN('[injection]') without parentheses or comma

Tags: web-application, sql-injection, mysql

I have the following injection:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN('[injection]');
```

And I can use these characters: `` !#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.- `` . So I can exit the single-quoted string via `'`, but I can't exit the `IN` clause because I don't have `)`.

My idea was to exploit this as blind SQLi while staying inside the existing `IN` clause, eg by injecting `1',sleep(5),'2`. But that won't work because I have neither `,` nor `(`.

The DBMS is MySQL, but I'd be interested in injections that work for any DBMS.